# Spring aop aspect is not triggering

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a spring component with a method I need to check:

```
String methodA(String param) {
...//do something 
}
```

Now I create an aspect to catch method execution:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "is.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class LoggingAspect {
     
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.A.methodA(..))", returning = "result")
void logMethodA(String result) {
    ...//do something with result
}
```

In properties flag is set to true to trigger aspect

```
is.enabled=true
```

also tried `execution(* com.A.methodA(String))` and no changes.
Copied methods from working aspects, they get triggered, can't find the clue.

Comment: Check the following . 1. Is `methodA` triggered through an internal method call ? If yes , internal method calls cannot be adviced . 2. Is `LogginAspect` initialized as a bean . A complete reproducible code shared will help you find answers easily.

Comment: Yep, methodA is not called outside of class, just via other method, so its not possible to aspect it ?

Comment: Please go through my answer for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68194594/4214241)

Comment: This is a Spring AOP limitation and native AspectJ offers much more . Please read through this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614354/why-does-self-invocation-not-work-for-spring-proxies-e-g-with-aop) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your `LoggingAspect` is registered as a bean in the Spring context at all. Try to remove or change `@ConditionalOnProperty` to `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "is.enabled", havingValue = true, matchIfMissing = true)`.